# R: parse python dictionary over json into xts

Tags: python, r, json, xts

I create some xts objects, save them as csv files, upload them to google cloud platform,..., create a Python dictionary,  download the dictionary and get the results (several original files at once over a REST API) back in R with Rcurl.

I want to create the original xts object again, but can't properly parse the end result.

Here is the data flow:

One of the csv files looks like this (they all have the same structure):

[image: csv files]

The result in R is taken with:

```
library(RCurl)
all_files <- getURL("https://....")
all_parsed <- jsonlite::fromJSON(all_files)
```

,is a list, and looks like:
[image: result with Rcurl]

If I print the result with cat(all_parsed$`2020-09-24.csv`) , it has just the right structure for xts:

[image: output with cat(all_parsed$2020-09-24.csv)]

But I can't really use the data because of all the \n \" etc

I could try it with strsplit(...), but it's a lot of work.

Is there any better way to parse the result?

Sorry I can't provide better explanations/reproducible code - I could send the URL for Rcurl to some of you by mail.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(stringr)

# Example string
ex_str <- "\"Index\",\"E2202\"\n\"2020-09-04\",NA\n\"2020-12-02\",2.7"

# First, split on the \n which represents a new line 
ex_str <- str_split(ex_str, "\n")[[1]]

# Then, drop quotation marks
str_replace_all(ex_str, "\"", "")

[1] "Index,E2202"    "2020-09-04,NA"  "2020-12-02,2.7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you. I will complete your code with:

```
eex_str <- str_replace_all(ex_str, "\"", "")[-length(str_replace_all(ex_str, "\"", ""))]
index_string <- unlist(str_split(eex_str, ","))[c(TRUE,FALSE)] # 
data_string <- unlist(str_split(eex_str, ","))[c(FALSE,TRUE)] # both length 6
library(xts)
suppressWarnings(recreated_xts <- xts(x = as.numeric(data_string[-1]), order.by = as.Date(index_string[-1] ))) # supress  NAs introduced by coercion
colnames(recreated_xts) <- data_string[1]
recreated_xts
```